# C# app calling 64-bit C/C++ DLL crashes, but 32-bit version runs

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, dll

My C/C++ DLL is built for 32- and 64-bit Windows environments. Two programmers working in .NET (C# and VB.NET) say when they build their clients for 32-bit, everything runs correctly. But when they build for 64-bit, the run ends in an access violation.

I am not a .NET programmer, but I can load their process and step through the DLL code in C++ debugger. The .NET run definitely encounters corrupt memory that does not occur when the client is one I wrote in C++/VCL.

My question: Is there something special in the .NET project settings for interfacing to a **64-bit** C/C++ DLL that differs from what works under **32-bit**?

Possibly relevant but I can't prove it: The DLL is built with **Character Setting=Not Set** for UTF-8/ASCII. I don't know whether the VB.NET client is built for Unicode, but I assume that would create problems.

EDITED TO ADD declarations from the VB.NET, C# clients and the C++ DLL

```
Declare Function Edit_RunEdits Lib "EDITS50.DLL" (ByVal smfID As Integer, _
                                                  ByVal edit_set_tag As String, _
                                                  ByVal layout_tag As String, _
                                                  ByVal data As String, _
                                                  ByVal edit_options As Integer, _
                                                  ByRef errors_count As Integer, _
                                                  ByVal owner As IntPtr, _
                                                  ByVal callback_func As IntPtr) As Integer
```

This the C# declaration:

```
[DllImportAttribute("EDITS50.dll", EntryPoint = "Edit_RunEdits")]
    public static extern int Edit_RunEdits(int smfID, 
         [InAttribute()] [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string edit_set_tag, 
         [InAttribute()] [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string layout_tag, 
         [InAttribute()] [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string data, 
         int edit_options, 
         ref int errors_count, 
         System.IntPtr owner, 
         System.IntPtr callback_func);
```

This is the C++ side:

```
#define EDIT_API  __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall
extern "C" int EDIT_API Edit_RunEdits( const int smfID, const char* edit_set_tag, 
const char* layout_tag, 
const char* data, 
const int edit_options, 
int* errors_count, 
void* owner, 
void* callback_func);
```

Comment: Lots of things can go wrong - everything has to be "just right" for this kind of interop (.NET to C++) to work.  Since you don't describe anything, there's really not much to say beyond that.

Comment: Unless you explain/show how the C# code p/invokes (calls) the functions exported by the native DLL **exactly** and how those exported functions are declared **precisely**, the only thing we can say: "_Yep, something is wrong somewhere somehow in the way the C# code calls the functions exported by the DLL..._"

Comment: Thanks. I'll ask one of the programmers (who works in both C# and C++) to provide the precise information.

Comment: Please see added information, above.

Comment: Sorry... one more. I just added the C# version of the declaration, above.

Comment: One more thing to add info to the post before anyone can help (probably not me) is check `sizeof(int)` for x86/x64 builds of C++ code (suspicious as C# code you show  uses Int32 for both)

Comment: Where is the pointer for the callback_func coming from? Is the pointer provided by the .NET code, i.e., is the callback a .NET method? If so, does the callback method actually match precisely the signature and calling convention required for the callback?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, on Windows (as well as Linux, i guess), C `int` should always be 4 byte for x86 and x64 (i guess you thought about `long` which could potentially differ between x86 and x64 depending on compiler and platform). Anyway, double-checking doesn't hurt...

Comment: @elgonzo, The callback_func is a pointer to a function in the client app (.NET). But the process never makes it that far. This is a rules engine, and the memory corruption occurs the first time the DLL accesses a section of the "data" parameter. Again, this all works under 32-bit. I'm wondering if there is a project setting needed when the .NET app builds for 64-bit that maybe isn't getting set.

Comment: What do you mean with `section of the "data" parameter`? `data` is just a char pointer (generated by the marshaller, so there is little room for the .NET client to produce a bogus pointer). Now, it should be easy to verify where that pointer is pointing at, and whether the memory it is pointing at contains any Ansi or Unicode sequences or whether the pointer is borked in some way...

Comment: Now, you mentioned in your question briefly "UTF-8". Do you expect UTF-8 byte sequences that are not ASCII characters in your "data" parameter? From what i can tell, the default charset used by the .NET marshaller is CharSet.ANSI, which would not convert strings into UTF-8 (except for such such characters that obviously are pure ASCII and thus also are by definition UTF-8)

Comment: @elgonzo, I agree this should run smoothly. And from my 64-bit C++ app, it does. But something is off and I am truly baffled. My point about UTF-8 is that the DLL expects "not-UNICODE".

Answer (score 0):

I believe I may have found the problem. The project was built for AnyCPU, but under the x64 settings the Prefer32Bit setting was "true". I am asking the .NET programmers to try building explicitly for x64, and to look for and override all instances of Prefer32Bit (set them to "false").

Thank you, everyone, for your feedback.